# How do I configure ag so that it will also search for files beginning with a "."?

Tags: bash, search, ag

I'm using ag v 2.2.  How do I configure ag so that it will search for files beginning with a "." in addition to all other files?  I'm noticing I have a file like so

```
$ cat client/.env.production 
REACT_APP_PROXY=https://map.chicommons.coop
```

but when I search with "ag" using a term in that file, the term doesn't come up ...

```
$ ag 'map\.chicom' .
web/directory/settings.py
28:ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['127.0.0.1', 'localhost', 'dev.chicommons.coop', 'map.chicommons.coop']

client/config.js
3:    ? "map.chicommons.com"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ag` has a `--hidden` flag to include dotfiles:

```bsh
ag --hidden 'map\.chicom'
```

and an `--unrestricted` flag to include all files (it would normally ignore files excluded by `.gitignore`, `.hgignore`, or `.ignore` files):

```bsh
ag --unrestricted 'map\.chicom'
```